# Why is this code playing up (on python)?

Tags: python, average

I wanted to make an average calculator that calculates the average of all the numbers you put in together but the final answer isn't correct and gives me some weird number.

```
print ("This is the average calculator. Would you like to continue? y/n")
rep=input()
rep= str (rep)
y1 = "y"
n1 = "n"

if rep == y1:
    print ("Okay")
    print ("How many times do you want to input numbers?")
    times=input()
    times=int(times)

for x in range (0, times):
    print ("Enter numbers")
    nums=input()
nums=int(nums) 
print (nums / times) 




elif rep == n1:
    print ("Too bad... bye!")
```

Comment: You're overwriting the nums var

Answer (score 4):

You are overriding `nums` in each iteration of the loop instead of accumulating them:

```
nums = 0
for x in range (0, times):
    print ("Enter numbers")
    nums += int(input())
```